# 7 Segments display with arduino mega2560

Tags: arduino-mega, display

I doing a small project with 6 display 7 segment (I will call A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6) and 3 cd4543B (I will call Da, Db, Dc) with an arduino mega 2560. I also use 6 transistor to control power supply of display.

Da is use for A1, A2

Db is use for A3, A4

Dc is use for A5, A6

The circuit is done, and work if I use only 4 display I have tried different combination (A1, A2, A3, A4, or A1, A2, A5, A6 or A2, A3, A4, A5, or A3, A4, A5, A6) and all work well.

but If I want to use five or six display, nothing work....

[image: here a diagram of my circuit]

there is resistance for each segment of each display which not appear on the diagram.

my code for 5 display :

```
//Da
const int bit_A=8;
const int bit_B=9;
const int bit_C=10;
const int bit_D=11;
//Db
const int bit_E=22;
const int bit_F=24;
const int bit_G=26;
const int bit_H=28;
//Dc
const int bit_I=40;
const int bit_J=42;
const int bit_K=44;
const int bit_L=46;

// transistors
const int alim_dizainemillier= 3;
const int alim_millier=4;
const int alim_centaine=5;
const int alim_dizaine=6;
const int alim_unite=7;

void setup()
{

pinMode(bit_A,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_B,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_C,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_D,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_E,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_F,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_G,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_H,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_I,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_J,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_K,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_L,OUTPUT);
pinMode(alim_dizainemillier,OUTPUT);
pinMode(alim_millier,OUTPUT);
pinMode(alim_centaine,OUTPUT);
pinMode(alim_dizaine,OUTPUT);
pinMode(alim_unite,OUTPUT);

digitalWrite(bit_A,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_B,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_C,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_D,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_E,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_F,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_G,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_H,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_I,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_J,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_K,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_L,LOW);
digitalWrite(alim_dizainemillier,LOW);
digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);
digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);
digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);  
}

void loop() 
{
 for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
 {
   afficher_nombre(i);

 }
}




void afficher_nombre(int nombre)

{
 long temps;
 int unite=0,dizaine=0,centaine=0, millier=0, dizainemillier=0;
 dizainemillier=nombre/10000;
 millier=(nombre-(10000*dizainemillier))/1000;
 centaine=(nombre-1000*millier)-(10000+dizainemillier)/100;
 dizaine=(nombre-(centaine*100)-(millier*1000)-(dizainemillier*10000))/10;
 unite=nombre-(dizainemillier*10000)-(millier*1000)-(centaine*100)-(dizaine*10);

 temps=millis();
 while((millis()-temps)<500){   



    digitalWrite(alim_dizainemillier,HIGH);
    afficher_CD(dizainemillier);
    digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);
    delay(5);


    digitalWrite(alim_dizainemillier,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_millier,HIGH);
    afficher_CM(millier);
    digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);
    delay(5);


   digitalWrite(alim_dizainemillier,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_centaine,HIGH);
   afficher_CM(centaine);
   digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);
   delay(5);


   digitalWrite(alim_dizainemillier,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,HIGH);
   afficher_UD(dizaine);
   digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);
   delay(5);

   digitalWrite(alim_dizainemillier,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_unite,HIGH);
   afficher_UD(unite);
   delay(5);
 }
}


void afficher_UD(int chiffre)
{
  digitalWrite(bit_A,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_B,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_C,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_D,LOW);

      if(chiffre>=8)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_D,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-8;
         }
     if(chiffre>=4)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_C,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-4;
         }
    if(chiffre>=2)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_B,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-2;
         }
    if(chiffre>=1)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_A,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-1;
         }
}


void afficher_CM(int chiffre)
{
  digitalWrite(bit_E,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_F,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_G,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_H,LOW);

      if(chiffre>=8)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_H,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-8;
         }
     if(chiffre>=4)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_G,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-4;
         }
    if(chiffre>=2)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_F,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-2;
         }
    if(chiffre>=1)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_E,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-1;
         }
}

void afficher_CD(int chiffre)
{
  digitalWrite(bit_I,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_J,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_K,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_L,LOW);

      if(chiffre>=8)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_L,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-8;
         }
     if(chiffre>=4)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_K,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-4;
         }
    if(chiffre>=2)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_J,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-2;
         }
    if(chiffre>=1)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_I,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-1;
         }
}
```

I don't understand why it's not working. Could it be a power supply problem ? even if there is never two display used at the same time (delay between them, see code)

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link [Arduino and CD4543](http://www.learnerswings.com/2014/04/control-common-cathode-seven-segment.html)

To control a common cathode seven segment display using CD4543

```
PH ( Pin 6 ) should be set LOW.
LD ( Pin 1 ) should be set HIGH.
BL ( Pin 7 ) should be set LOW.
```

[image]

Try this code for each segment, could be faulty segment too :)

```
int Ph  = 6;      //arduino pin connected to the Ph pin of 4543
int BL  = 5;     //arduino pin connected to the BL pin of 4543
int LD  = 11;   //arduino pin connected to the LD pin of 4543


int A   = 7;
int B   = 9;
int C   = 10;
int D   = 8;

void setup()
{     
    // Declare all the pins as OUTPUT pins

  pinMode(Ph,  OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BL,  OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LD, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(A , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(B  , OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C  , OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(D, OUTPUT);

}

void loop()
{

    // Display 0

  digitalWrite(Ph,  LOW); 
  digitalWrite(BL,  LOW);   
  digitalWrite(LD,  HIGH); 

  digitalWrite(A , LOW); 
  digitalWrite(B , LOW);   
  digitalWrite(C , LOW);
  digitalWrite(D , LOW);

  delay(1000);

    // Display 1

  digitalWrite(A , HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(B , LOW);   
  digitalWrite(C , LOW);
  digitalWrite(D , LOW);

  delay(1000);

    // Display 2

  digitalWrite(A , LOW); 
  digitalWrite(B , HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(C , LOW);
  digitalWrite(D , LOW);

  delay(1000);

    // Display 3

  digitalWrite(A , HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(B , HIGH);   
  digitalWrite(C , LOW);
  digitalWrite(D , LOW);

  delay(1000);

    // Display 4

  digitalWrite(A , LOW); 
  digitalWrite(B , LOW);   
  digitalWrite(C , HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D , LOW);

  delay(1000); 
}
```

Comment: This 3 pin on the CD4543 are already well linked... I have done a better post with video of my problem : https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/38374/7-segment-displays-arduino-mega-2560

Answer (score -1):

> The circuit is done,

unnecessarily complex: you can share the data lines among the drivers.