# 7 segment displays arduino mega 2560

Tags: display, atmega2560

I'm trying to use an Arduino Mega 2560 to use 7-segment displays, 6 displays... I use 3 CD4543B to pilot the 6 displays.

It works very well for 4 displays as you can see in this [video](https://youtu.be/cTKuFk76ZP0).

But when I want to use the same circuit for 5 or 6 displays, there is some bug as you can see on this [video](https://youtu.be/boCAtVDET5w) for 5 displays.

Here is the code that works fine for 4 displays:

```
//définition des broches du premier décodeur 
const int bit_A=8;
const int bit_B=9;
const int bit_C=10;
const int bit_D=11;
//définition du brochage du deuxieme decodeur 
const int bit_E=22;
const int bit_F=24;
const int bit_G=26;
const int bit_H=28;
//définition du brochage du 3ième décodeur
const int bit_I=40;
const int bit_J=42;
const int bit_K=44;
const int bit_L=46;
//définition des broches des transistors

const int alim_millier=3;
const int alim_centaine=4;
const int alim_dizaine=5;
const int alim_unite=6;

void setup() {
  //les broches sont toutes des sorties
  pinMode(bit_A,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_B,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_C,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_D,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_E,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_F,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_G,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_H,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_I,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_J,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_K,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_L,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(alim_millier,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(alim_centaine,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(alim_dizaine,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(alim_unite,OUTPUT);
  //les broches sont toutes mises à l'état bas
  digitalWrite(bit_A,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_B,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_C,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_D,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_E,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_F,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_G,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_H,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_I,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_J,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_K,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_L,LOW);
  digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
  digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);
  digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);
  digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);
}

void loop() {
  //fonction principale
  for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    //boucle qui permet de compter de0 à9999(=10000 valeurs)
    afficher_nombre(i);//appelde la fonction affichage avec envoi du nombre à afficher
  }
}

//fonction permettant d'afficherun nombre sur quatre afficheurs
void afficher_nombre(int nombre) {
  long temps;//variable utilisée poursavoir le temps écoulé
  int unite=0,dizaine=0,centaine=0, millier=0;//variable pour chaque afficheur
  millier=nombre/1000;//on récupère les milliers
  centaine=(nombre-1000*millier)/100;//on récupère les centaines
  dizaine=(nombre-(centaine*100)-(millier*1000))/10;//on récupère les dizaines
  unite=nombre-(millier*1000)-(centaine*100)-(dizaine*10);//on récupère les unités
  temps=millis();//on récupère le temps courant
  //tant qu'on a pas affiché ce chiffre pendant au moins 500 milliseconde
  //permet donc de pouvoir lire le nombre affiché
  while((millis()-temps)<500) {
    //on affiche le nombre
    //d'abord les milliers pendant 5ms
    digitalWrite(alim_millier,HIGH);
    afficher_CD(millier);//on appelle la fonction qui permet d'afficher le chiffre millier
    digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);//le transistor est bloqué
    digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);//le transistor est bloqué
    delay(5);
    //d'abord les centaines pendant 5ms
    digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_centaine,HIGH);//le transistor de l'afficheur des centaines est saturé, donc l'afficheur est allumé
    afficher_CM(centaine);//on appelle la fonction qui permet d'afficher le chiffre centaine  
    digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);//le transistor est bloqué
    digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);//le transistor est bloqué
    delay(5);
    //ensuite les dizaines pendant 5 ms
    digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);// transistor est bloqué
    digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,HIGH);//transistor saturé
    afficher_CM(dizaine);
    digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);//transistor bloqué
    delay(5);
    //on affiche les unités 5 ms
    digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);//transistor bloqué
    digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);//transistor bloqué
    digitalWrite(alim_unite,HIGH);//transistor saturé
    afficher_UD(unite);
    delay(5);
  }
}

//fonction écrivant sur les premiers afficheurs
void afficher_UD(int chiffre) {
  digitalWrite(bit_A,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_B,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_C,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_D,LOW);
  if(chiffre>=8) {
    digitalWrite(bit_D,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-8;
  }
  if(chiffre>=4) {
    digitalWrite(bit_C,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-4;
  }
  if(chiffre>=2) {
    digitalWrite(bit_B,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-2;
  }
  if(chiffre>=1) {
    digitalWrite(bit_A,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-1;
  }
}

//fonction écrivant sur le second afficheur
void afficher_CM(int chiffre) {
  digitalWrite(bit_E,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_F,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_G,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_H,LOW);
  if(chiffre>=8) {
    digitalWrite(bit_H,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-8;
  }
  if(chiffre>=4) {
    digitalWrite(bit_G,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-4;
  }
  if(chiffre>=2) {
    digitalWrite(bit_F,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-2;
  }
  if(chiffre>=1) {
    digitalWrite(bit_E,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-1;
  }
}

void afficher_CD(int chiffre) {
  digitalWrite(bit_I,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_J,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_K,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_L,LOW);
  if(chiffre>=8) {
    digitalWrite(bit_L,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-8;
  }
  if(chiffre>=4) {
    digitalWrite(bit_K,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-4;
  }
  if(chiffre>=2) {
    digitalWrite(bit_J,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-2;
  }
  if(chiffre>=1) {
    digitalWrite(bit_I,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-1;
  }
}
```

And here the code for 5 displays with "bugs" :

```
//définition des broches du premier décodeur 
const int bit_A=8;
const int bit_B=9;
const int bit_C=10;
const int bit_D=11;
//définition du brochage du deuxieme decodeur 
const int bit_E=22;
const int bit_F=24;
const int bit_G=26;
const int bit_H=28;
//définition du brochage du 3ième décodeur
const int bit_I=40;
const int bit_J=42;
const int bit_K=44;
const int bit_L=46;
//définition des broches des transistors
const int alim_dm= 3;
const int alim_millier=4;
const int alim_centaine=5;
const int alim_dizaine=6;
const int alim_unite=7;
void setup() {
  //les broches sont toutes des sorties
  pinMode(bit_A,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_B,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_C,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_D,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_E,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_F,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_G,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_H,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_I,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_J,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_K,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_L,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(alim_dm,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(alim_millier,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(alim_centaine,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(alim_dizaine,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(alim_unite,OUTPUT);
  //les broches sont toutes mises à l'état bas
  digitalWrite(bit_A,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_B,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_C,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_D,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_E,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_F,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_G,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_H,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_I,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_J,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_K,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_L,LOW);
  digitalWrite(alim_dm,LOW);
  digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
  digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);
  digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);
  digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);  
}

void loop() {
  //fonction principale
  for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)//boucle qui permet de compter de0 à 99999(=100000 valeurs) {
    afficher_nombre(i);//appelde la fonction affichage avec envoi du nombre à afficher
  }
}

//fonction permettant d'afficherun nombre sur quatre afficheurs
void afficher_nombre(int nombre) {
  long temps;//variable utilisée poursavoir le temps écoulé
  int unite=0,dizaine=0,centaine=0, millier=0, dm=0;//variable pour chaque afficheur
  dm=nombre/10000;//on récupère les dm
  millier=(nombre-(10000*dm))/1000;//on récupère les milliers
  centaine=(nombre-1000*millier)-(10000+dm)/100;//on récupère les centaines
  dizaine=(nombre-(centaine*100)-(millier*1000)-(dm*10000))/10;//on récupère les dizaines
  unite=nombre-(dm*10000)-(millier*1000)-(centaine*100)-(dizaine*10);//on récupère les unités

  temps=millis();//on récupère le temps courant
  //tant qu'on a pas affiché ce chiffre pendant au moins 500 milliseconde
  //permet donc de pouvoir lire le nombre affiché
  while((millis()-temps)<500) {
    //on affiche le nombre
    //d'abord les dms pendant 5ms
    digitalWrite(alim_dm,HIGH);
    afficher_CD(dm);//on appelle la fonction qui permet d'afficher le chiffre dm
    digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);//le transistor bloqué
    digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);//le transistor est bloqué
    digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);//le transistor est bloqué
    digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);//le transistor bloqué
    delay(10);
    //d'abord les millier pendant 5ms
    digitalWrite(alim_dm,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_millier,HIGH);//le transistor de l'afficheur des centaines est saturé, donc l'afficheur est allumé
    afficher_CM(millier);//on appelle la fonction qui permet d'afficher le chiffre centaine  
    digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);//le transistor est bloqué
    digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);//le transistor est bloqué
    digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);//le transistor bloqué
    delay(10);
    //ensuite les centaine pendant 5 ms
    digitalWrite(alim_dm,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_centaine,HIGH);// transistor est bloqué
    afficher_CM(centaine);
    digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);//transistor saturé
    digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);//transistor bloqué
    delay(10);
    //on affiche les dizaines 5 ms
    digitalWrite(alim_dm,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);//transistor bloqué
    digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,HIGH);//transistor bloqué
    afficher_UD(dizaine);
    digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);//transistor saturé
    delay(10);
    //on affiche les unités
    digitalWrite(alim_dm,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);//transistor bloqué
    digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);//transistor bloqué
    digitalWrite(alim_unite,HIGH);//transistor saturé
    afficher_UD(unite);
    delay(10);
  }
}

//fonction écrivant sur les premiers afficheurs
void afficher_UD(int chiffre) {
  digitalWrite(bit_A,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_B,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_C,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_D,LOW);
  if(chiffre>=8) {
    digitalWrite(bit_D,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-8;
  }
  if(chiffre>=4) {
    digitalWrite(bit_C,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-4;
  }
  if(chiffre>=2) {
    digitalWrite(bit_B,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-2;
  }
  if(chiffre>=1) {
    digitalWrite(bit_A,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-1;
  }
}

//fonction écrivant sur le second afficheur
void afficher_CM(int chiffre) {
  digitalWrite(bit_E,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_F,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_G,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_H,LOW);
  if(chiffre>=8) {
    digitalWrite(bit_H,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-8;
  }
  if(chiffre>=4) {
    digitalWrite(bit_G,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-4;
  }
  if(chiffre>=2) {
    digitalWrite(bit_F,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-2;
  }
  if(chiffre>=1) {
    digitalWrite(bit_E,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-1;
  }
}

void afficher_CD(int chiffre) {
  digitalWrite(bit_I,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_J,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_K,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_L,LOW);
  if(chiffre>=8) {
    digitalWrite(bit_L,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-8;
  }
  if(chiffre>=4) {
    digitalWrite(bit_K,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-4;
  }
  if(chiffre>=2) {
    digitalWrite(bit_J,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-2;
  }
  if(chiffre>=1) {
    digitalWrite(bit_I,HIGH);
    chiffre=chiffre-1;
  }
}
//Fin du programme
```

I've been trying for weeks to understand the problem. All displays work fine, and if I adapt the code for 4 displays and try to use any 4 of the 6 displays it works fine (I have tried a combination such as displays: 1, 2, 3, 4 or 2, 3, 4, 5 or 3, 4, 5, 6 or 1, 2, 5, 6, everything works).

Thanks to a conversation on [the Arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=475902.msg3261509#msg3261509), I also tried this code for 5 displays but I still have the same problem:

```
//Da
const int bit_A=8;
const int bit_B=9;
const int bit_C=10;
const int bit_D=11;
//Db
const int bit_E=22;
const int bit_F=24;
const int bit_G=26;
const int bit_H=28;
//Dc
const int bit_I=40;
const int bit_J=42;
const int bit_K=44;
const int bit_L=46;
// transistors
const int alim_dizainemillier= 3;
const int alim_millier=4;
const int alim_centaine=5;
const int alim_dizaine=6;
const int alim_unite=7;
void setup() {
  pinMode(bit_A,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_B,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_C,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_D,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_E,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_F,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_G,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_H,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_I,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_J,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_K,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bit_L,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(alim_dizainemillier,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(alim_millier,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(alim_centaine,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(alim_dizaine,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(alim_unite,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(bit_A,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_B,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_C,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_D,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_E,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_F,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_G,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_H,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_I,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_J,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_K,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_L,LOW);
  digitalWrite(alim_dizainemillier,LOW);
  digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
  digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);
  digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);
  digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);
}

void loop() {
  for(int i=0;i<100000;i++) {
    afficher_nombre(i);
    delay(5);
  }
}


void afficher_nombre(int nombre) {
  long temps;
  int unite=0,dizaine=0,centaine=0, millier=0, dizainemillier=0;
  dizainemillier=nombre/10000;
  millier=(nombre-(10000*dizainemillier))/1000;
  centaine=(nombre-(1000*millier)-(10000*dizainemillier))/100;
  dizaine=(nombre-(centaine*100)-(millier*1000)-(dizainemillier*10000))/10;
  unite=nombre-(dizainemillier*10000)-(millier*1000)-(centaine*100)-(dizaine*10);
  temps=millis();
  while((millis()-temps)<500){
    afficher_CD(dizainemillier);
    digitalWrite(alim_dizainemillier, HIGH);
    delay(5);
    digitalWrite(alim_dizainemillier, LOW);
    afficher_CM(millier);
    digitalWrite(alim_millier, HIGH);
    delay(5);
    digitalWrite(alim_millier, LOW);
    afficher_CM(centaine);
    digitalWrite(alim_centaine, HIGH);
    delay(5);
    digitalWrite(alim_centaine, LOW);
    afficher_UD(dizaine);
    digitalWrite(alim_dizaine, HIGH);
    delay(5);
    digitalWrite(alim_dizaine, LOW);
    afficher_UD(unite);
    digitalWrite(alim_unite, HIGH);
    delay(5);
    digitalWrite(alim_unite, LOW);
  }
}

void afficher_UD(int chiffre) {
  digitalWrite(bit_A,chiffre & 1);
  digitalWrite(bit_B,chiffre & 2);
  digitalWrite(bit_C,chiffre & 4);
  digitalWrite(bit_D,chiffre & 8);
}

void afficher_CM(int chiffre) {
  digitalWrite(bit_E,chiffre & 1);
  digitalWrite(bit_F,chiffre & 2);
  digitalWrite(bit_G,chiffre & 4);
  digitalWrite(bit_H,chiffre & 8);
}

void afficher_CD(int chiffre) {
  digitalWrite(bit_I,chiffre & 1);
  digitalWrite(bit_J,chiffre & 2);
  digitalWrite(bit_K,chiffre & 4);
  digitalWrite(bit_L,chiffre & 8);
}
```

Any clue is very welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because I use `int` and I should use `long` to avoid overflow... for the number I want to display:

```
void loop() 
{
 for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
 {
   afficher_nombre(i);
   delay(5);
 }
}
```

should be :

```
void loop() 
{
 for(long i=0;i<100000;i++)
 {
   afficher_nombre(i);
   delay(5);
 }
}
```

And also a parentheses problem solved thanks to cattledog on [this forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=475902.15)

Comment: on Arduino `int` is 16-bit (2-byte) value. This yields a range of -32,768 to 32,767 while `long` is 32 bits (4 bytes), from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

Comment: exactly :) ! I'm use to code for 64bits or 32bits on computer, and forgot that arduino is 16bits....

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the code that works fine for 4 displays:

both code pieces suffer from the use of "delay()".

here is what I used - https://dannyelectronics.wordpress.com/2017/06/30/a-more-flexible-driver-for-7-segment-leds/

it is written so the leds can be driven by individual pins so porting to  arduino requires no change to the source code - just a few macros to remap the IO operations.

also running it from a timer isr is the (only) way to go.

edit: here is to show how the code above gets to work here. I expanded it to cover 8 digits but only the first 6 digits effective. three macros are all it takes to repurpose it for arduino.

displaying a fixed "123456".

[image]

all the user code does is to dump the content to be displayed into the display buffer and the display routine, led_display() takes care of the rest.